# Закрыть доступ к сайту по ip адресу сервера на котором он лежит

Tags: nginx, apache2, vesta, digitalocean

с сервером работаю по минимуму, появилась необходимость закрыть доступ к сайту по его ip адресу. 
Сервер: digitaOcean
Панель управления сервером: VestaCp nginx/apache2

Буду рад, если кто то подскажет как это реализовать.
Спасибо

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что закрыть доступ к серверу или чтобы был доступ только по доменному имени?

Comment: Да, все верно.
Пока, что воспользовался "вариантом конкретно для этой панели управления" но так же был бы рад увидеть альтернативные варианты, так как ранее такого не делал.